# Incorrect number of dimensions when selecting cell

Tags: r

Below is the data I own.

Why can't I input this code **price[10, 3]**?

```
time month price quantity temperature rainfall    CPI average_wage unemployment_rate

1   200301     1 192.7 214641.0        16.6     22.9  90.25        73045              5.03

2   200302     2 150.4 161648.1        18.7     50.4  88.99        39401              5.17

3   200303     3 165.7 236169.1        19.4    106.4  88.71        37952              5.08

4   200304     4 214.6 215096.0        23.2     97.9  89.68        38309              4.92

5   200305     5 207.9 143308.0        25.6    162.6  89.63        38850              4.98

6   200306     6 192.4 132486.1        26.6    112.8  89.11        38336              5.09

7   200307     7 200.3 165110.5        29.4      2.5  88.74        38875              5.16

8   200308     8 159.9 272767.9        28.7    223.2  89.07        39694              5.21

9   200309     9 148.6 274986.5        28.3      5.0  89.34        40670              5.05

10  200310    10 149.6 331286.1        25.4      0.6  89.98        38292              4.92

11  200311    11 177.5 205597.9        22.7      1.8  89.58        38138              4.71

12  200312    12 199.9 146320.5        18.2      0.0  89.56        43422              4.58

13  200401     1 226.5 201832.5        16.7      3.7  90.26        75920              4.53

14  200402     2 185.6 216579.7        17.1     26.7  89.56        39580              4.61

15  200403     3 214.6 164778.2        18.7     24.0  89.50        38952              4.45

16  200404     4 237.0 156777.3        23.1     68.2  90.53        38740              4.36

17  200405     5 256.8 145234.4        26.3     82.5  90.45        38844              4.41

18  200406     6 221.6 125163.0        27.6      1.8  90.66        39956              4.54

19  200407     7 224.7 116610.9        27.9    372.9  91.70        39858              4.62

20  200408     8 178.1 244932.8        28.5    188.2  91.34        41081              4.67

21  200409     9 164.9 197334.5        27.3    353.1  91.83        40131              4.50

22  200410    10 170.3 248996.2        24.1      6.0  92.13        38736              4.31

23  200411    11 180.1 168696.4        22.7      0.7  90.95        38460              4.14

24  200412    12 184.5 201819.0        19.4     87.8  91.01        42704              4.09

25  200501     1 166.5 191108.3        15.4      9.8  90.70        65044              4.06

26  200502     2 223.0 149772.3        16.3     58.3  91.30        55615              4.28

27  200503     3 164.1 221622.8        17.2    149.6  91.56        39102              4.15

28  200504     4 212.3 172360.7        23.5     30.9  92.02        38800              4.04

29  200505     5 236.2 129725.0        26.3    131.2  92.53        38987              4.10

30  200506     6 189.4 118555.5        27.6    313.0  92.82        40013              4.22
```

Why can't I input this code **price[10, 3]**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood well your question. If you want the 10th row and the third column, it works.

```
library(tidyverse)
tib_price <- tribble(
  ~time, ~month, ~price, ~quantity, ~temperature, ~rainfall, ~CPI, ~average_wage, ~unemployment_rate,
  200301, 1, 192.7, 214641.0, 16.6, 22.9, 90.25, 73045, 5.03,
  200302, 2, 150.4, 161648.1, 18.7, 50.4, 88.99, 39401, 5.17,
  200303, 3, 165.7, 236169.1, 19.4, 106.4, 88.71, 37952, 5.08,
  200304, 4, 214.6, 215096.0, 23.2, 97.9, 89.68, 38309, 4.92,
  200305, 5, 207.9, 143308.0, 25.6, 162.6, 89.63, 38850, 4.98,
  200306, 6, 192.4, 132486.1, 26.6, 112.8, 89.11, 38336, 5.09,
  200307, 7, 200.3, 165110.5, 29.4, 2.5, 88.74, 38875, 5.16,
  200308, 8, 159.9, 272767.9, 28.7, 223.2, 89.07, 39694, 5.21,
  200309, 9, 148.6, 274986.5, 28.3, 5.0, 89.34, 40670, 5.05,
  200310, 10, 149.6, 331286.1, 25.4, 0.6, 89.98, 38292, 4.92,
  200311, 11, 177.5, 205597.9, 22.7, 1.8, 89.58, 38138, 4.71,
  200312, 12, 199.9, 146320.5, 18.2, 0.0, 89.56, 43422, 4.58,
  200401, 1, 226.5, 201832.5, 16.7, 3.7, 90.26, 75920, 4.53,
  200402, 2, 185.6, 216579.7, 17.1, 26.7, 89.56, 39580, 4.61,
  200403, 3, 214.6, 164778.2, 18.7, 24.0, 89.50, 38952, 4.45,
  200404, 4, 237.0, 156777.3, 23.1, 68.2, 90.53, 38740, 4.36,
  200405, 5, 256.8, 145234.4, 26.3, 82.5, 90.45, 38844, 4.41,
  200406, 6, 221.6, 125163.0, 27.6, 1.8, 90.66, 39956, 4.54,
  200407, 7, 224.7, 116610.9, 27.9, 372.9, 91.70, 39858, 4.62,
  200408, 8, 178.1, 244932.8, 28.5, 188.2, 91.34, 41081, 4.67,
  200409, 9, 164.9, 197334.5, 27.3, 353.1, 91.83, 40131, 4.50,
  200410, 10, 170.3, 248996.2, 24.1, 6.0, 92.13, 38736, 4.31,
  200411, 11, 180.1, 168696.4, 22.7, 0.7, 90.95, 38460, 4.14,
  200412, 12, 184.5, 201819.0, 19.4, 87.8, 91.01, 42704, 4.09,
  200501, 1, 166.5, 191108.3, 15.4, 9.8, 90.70, 65044, 4.06,
  200502, 2, 223.0, 149772.3, 16.3, 58.3, 91.30, 55615, 4.28,
  200503, 3, 164.1, 221622.8, 17.2, 149.6, 91.56, 39102, 4.15,
  200504, 4, 212.3, 172360.7, 23.5, 30.9, 92.02, 38800, 4.04,
  200505, 5, 236.2, 129725.0, 26.3, 131.2, 92.53, 38987, 4.10,
  200506, 6, 189.4, 118555.5, 27.6, 313.0, 92.82, 40013, 4.22
)
tib_price[10, 3]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   price
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  150.
```